# snapshot.key to string variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set a variable to a snapshot.key value. So far my variable returns `interlocutor = [object Promise]`, but I want to set it to the actual value, for example SEV9iTd8whgf0VyIbqUiVNaTcAL2 which is the key of the node.

How can I do that?

```js
this.interlocutor = this.getRandomInterlocutor();


  FriendlyChat.prototype.getRandomInterlocutor = async function(){
    var numberOfUsers = await this.getNumberOfUsersRef();

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers);
    if(randomIndex == 0){
      randomIndex = 1;
    }
    
    var ref = await firebase.database().ref('companies/' + this.company + '/users/');
    ref.orderByChild('order').equalTo(randomIndex).on('value', function(userSnapshot) {
    userSnapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        this.interlocutor = userSnapshot.key;
        return val.userSnapshot.key;
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Probably you should use a promise syntax when subscribing to the 'value', as in example [firebase-docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), so it could look like `.on('value').then(function(userSnapshot) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Comapanies/'+'Company/'+'User/');
ref.orderByChild('order').equalTo(1).on('value', function(userSnapshot) {
    userSnapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        //this.interlocutor = userSnapshot.key;
       document.getElementById("Key").innerHTML= userSnapshot.key
    });
});
```

see my working example here [Js Fiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ru11u0dg/)